# For SDRAM, how to tell how many ranks supported in each channel?

Tags: memory, sdram

This is from Wiki:

> As an example, take an i945 memory controller with
> four Kingston KHX6400D2/1G memory modules, where each module has a
> capacity of 1 GiB. Kingston describes each module as composed of 16
> "64M×8-bit" chips with each chip having an 8-bit-wide data bus. 16 × 8
> equals 128, therefore, each module has two ranks of 64 bits each. So,
> from the MCH point of view there are four 1 GB modules. At a higher
> logical level, the MCH also sees two channels, each with four ranks.

The article says that there are two channels and each with four ranks. I am not sure how this is derived? The author seems to assume each channel can support 4 physical ranks. Why the system is not actually using 4 channels with 2 ranks per channel?

Thanks!

Comment: "Why the system is not actually using 4 channels with 2 ranks per channel?"  Because that requires a lot more pins, larger memory controller footprint, more PCB layers to escape the extra signals, and so on.

Comment: If two ranks share the same 64 bit bus you have half the maximum bandwidth but a much less expensive board and a cheaper CPU as well. 4 channel memory is used on Intels HEDT boards. In spite of the expense, often performance is not much different between running them with 2 channels active vs. 4 so it's a pretty reasonable tradeoff.

Comment: I see. Thanks. 

I understand that sharing more ranks within a physical channel can increase the load on high-speed IOs thus causing performance degradation. 

My original question is how to tell whether it is 4 rank per channel or 2 ranks per channel from the descriptions. However, it seems like it is a commonly assumed fact that 2 rank per channel is a de facto design widely used.